# How to handle php static class variables inside functions

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm writing a simple logic for testing purposes. When an action method is called I grab the id that is passed as parameter to the action and store it in an associative array. I wrote an static function to handle the logic. I have a second problem too, I want to check if the id is already present as a key in the associative array, if it is, I want to increment the counter. But I can open another question for that problem. The purpose for this question is the static variable not working.

```
class UsersController extends Controller

 static $users= Array();

 public function show( $id)
   { 
      $this::stats($id);
   }

 private static function stats($id)
   {

      if(  array_key_exists("{$id}", UsersController::$users))
       {
           UsersController::$users["{$id}"] += 1;
       }
       else
       {
           UsersController::$users["{$id}"] = 1;
      }
   print_r(UsersController::$users);
   }
```

Each time a visit a different user www.example.com/users/2 or  www.example.com/users/1. the print_r statement shows that only one element exists in the array. Am I missing some oop principle. I wrote a similar code in a C# and it worked just as expected.

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in quotes?  Don't use `"{$id}"`, use `$id`, so much more readable.  Also, the keyword `static` can be used in place of the current class name.  This would make refactoring much easier later on.

Comment: @Devon: sorry to hijack potentially, but is the use of `self` also acceptable?

Comment: @Kisaragi, yes, but it depends.  Sometimes self is better.   It applies differently when classes are extended.  Example: self in Controller will always refer to Controller.  static in Controller will refer to the called class (UsersController) allowing functionality to be extended.

Comment: `$this !== self`. Are you using your `show` method like that? Static methods and properties are accessed with `self::` in PHP, not `$this->`... definitely not `$this::`.

Comment: @PHPglue suprisingly, $this:: does work, never tried it before but I tested it last night on PHP7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing any OOP principle, you're missing the standard implementation of PHP processes.  Normally, web servers are designed to have php scripts execute then die.  There is no persistence in memory when you visit two different pages.

Can you implement PHP to continue serving with the same memory?  Surely could, but no web server implementation I know of works this way.

Most people use sessions (server side) or cookies (client side) to keep persistent data across multiple requests.

Comment: Yes, my issue is because the way requests are handled.

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the data in a permanent storage to persist through multiple requests.

Each PHP request is a completely fresh execution. So if it was your C# code, it would be as if you exited the C# program, started it up again and visited with the second user.

Often used sources of permanent storage with PHP include options like storing it in a file, database, etc.

If the storage of this data can be per user and not a big deal if lost, you can store it in sessions (stored on your server, typically in file) or cookies (stored in client's browser). Neither of these storage mediums are very reliable and is considered temporary.

There are even more temporary forms of data storage and they include things like Memcache (independent memory based storage medium), redis (ditto), APCu (can be built into PHP as a module), etc.